# Filter relationship, based on array of integers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My model has many options, multiple fields of a single option store values as an **array** on integers.

I want to filter based on an integer is included.
in php similare to **in_array()**, but the array is stored in db, and the number is key word.

```
$productsWithOptions = [
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"mac 2",
            "options":[
                {
                    "id":4,
                    "price":99.9,
                    "product_id":2,
                    "colors":"[4,3,2]",
                    "sizes":"[5,3,2]"
                },
                {
                    "id":5,
                    "price":99.9,
                    "product_id":2,
                    "colors":"[4,4,5]",
                    "sizes":"[1,2,2]"
                },
                {
                    "id":7,
                    "name":"mac 7",
                    "options":[
                        {
                            "id":19,
                            "price":99.9,
                            "product_id":7,
                            "colors":"[6,3,4]",
                            "sizes":"[5,2,5]"
                        },
                        {
                            "id":20,
                            "price":1999.9,
                            "product_id":7,
                            "colors":"[1,6,6]",
                            "sizes":"[5,6,2]"
                        },
                        {
                            "id":21,
                            "price":1999.9,
                            "product_id":7,
                            "colors":"[4,6,5]",
                            "sizes":"[5,2,2]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
$products = Product::whereHas('options', function (Builder $query) use ($arr) {
                $query->where('colors','like', "%2%" );
            })->get();
```

This is how options table looks like in db.

[image]

Comment: You might want to start working with pivot tables if the colors are stored in the database.

If the searchable options are stored and linked using pivot tables you could use something like:

Product::whereHas('colors', function ($query) use ($product) {
                    $query->where('id', $product->color);
                })->get();

Comment: have you stired ```colors``` as json column in mysql ??

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai No, its just a an array, stored in text field. but its Serialized with the response.

Comment: please convert that to json or may be seperate table for sizes and add the relationship column so that you can search that easily

Comment: But storing it in text filelds make complicated for search and also performance

Comment: Going to test that and reply, later today.